# How to Populate the structure using a file(code attached below)?

Tags: c++, c, file, data-structures

I am trying to populate the structure using the file given at the bottom,please suggest some edits in the code so that I can print the structure as I have tried it in the main() function and this is my first time on stackoverflow,so pardon me for some errors I have made during posting this Question..

the file contents are one below the other and they are order in which the structure is declared (variable positions are same)

Please guide me to populate the structure properly and to print it in the main() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

//this code works on ZERO INDEXING
struct Empdetails
{
   char name[25];
   char id[8];
   char password[4];
   int casual;
   int medical;
   int earned;
} emp[5];//declaring array of structures

/*I am trying to convert the file to a structure and then use the 
structure to access the data and 
I'm also using files to store the information*/

extern void table()
{
   FILE *fp;//definig a file pointer
   char ch;
   char  line[4096];
   char *token;//token pointer that points to a 
   int tokenposition=0;//token here means the particular text separated by comma
   int lineposition=0;//line here is the entire line which has entire details of the an emmployee 
   fp=fopen("emplyoyeeinfo.txt","r");//opening the file and reading it

   while(fgets(line,4096,fp) !=NULL) //accessing the lines one by one and using a \n to recognize the end of a line
   {
       tokenposition=0;//when we tokenize the line we need the count to keep a track of where we are int he string
      //printf("%s \n",line);//used to check which line is not being read by the compiler
       token = strtok(line,",");//this seperates a line into token(entity) based on a delimiter,here the delimiter is a comma
       //string tokenization` 

       while(token != NULL)
       {
           switch(tokenposition)//acessing the required element through the tokenposition counter
           {
               case 0:
                   strcpy(emp[lineposition].name,token);
                   break;
               case 1:
                   strcpy(emp[lineposition].id,token);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   strcpy(emp[lineposition].password,token);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   emp[lineposition].casual=atoi(token);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   emp[lineposition].medical=atoi(token);
                   break;
               case 5:
                   emp[lineposition].earned=atoi(token);
                   break;
           }
           token =strtok(NULL,",");
       tokenposition++;//to access the next token in the same line
       }
       lineposition++;//after all the tokens are put in a structure,wwe move to the next line and redo the entire process
   }    
}

void main()
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tNAME : %s\033[0m\n", emp[i].name);
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tID : %s\033[0m\n", emp[i].id);
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tPASSWORD : %d\033[0m\n", emp[i].password);
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tCASUAL : %f\033[0m\n", emp[i].casual);
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tMEDICAL : %c\033[0m\n", emp[i].medical);
       printf("\033[34m\n\n\tEARNED : %s\033[0m\n", emp[i].earned);
   }
}
```

---

### file is (name,userid,password,casual leave,medical leave,earned leave)

```
Ramesh,QW120345,PO56,10,15,7
Rajesh,QW120905,IO56,10,15,7
Kajal,JI456987,IWQ9,10,15,7
Harleen,HJ782013,ZM12,10,15,7
Jim,BN784569,KL45,10,15,7
```

[output of the code when trying to print the structure is in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9NuV.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to actually call the `table()` function from your `main()` to invoke it before trying to print the contents of the structure. Otherwise, the structure (and any other variables in C) is initially populated with garbage values.
2. The `printf()` statements in your `main()` are not using the correct format specifiers to match the variables types defined in the `Empdeials` structure. Make sure you use the correct specifiers (see this page for further info on the specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)